# APPCRASH on a beginner C++ program , calling a public method on a function

Tags: c++, function, class, methods, linked-list

i'm new to `C++` and `OOP`.

I'm writing a `C++` program to manipulates a car list , i've defined a car class that has 5 properties ( `brand` , `name` , `engine` , `hp` and `speed` ) and has two public functions ( `readvalues()` : fills properties and `show()` : show propercties )

```
class car {
    string brand ;
    string model ;
    string engine ;
    int hp ;
    float speed ;

    public :
        void readvalues (){
            cout << "\n Brand :" ;
            getline(cin,brand,'\n');
            cout << " Model name :" ;
            getline(cin,model,'\n');
            cout << " Engine name :" ;
            getline(cin,engine,'\n');
            cout << " Horsepower :" ;
            cin >> hp ;
            hp = abs(hp);
            cout << " Max speed :" ;
            cin >> speed ;
            speed = abs(speed);
            cout << "  Done \n\n" ;
        }
        void show (){
            cout << " - "  << brand << " " <<model << " , " << engine << " " << hp << "hp " << fixed << setprecision(1) << speed << " km/h .\n" ;
        }
};
```

Then i defined my linked lists' data structure  , the nodes' type is clinked ( it contains a car and a pointer to another node )

```
typedef struct clinked {
    car kar ;
    struct clinked * next ;
}clinked;

typedef clinked * clist ;
```

Then i defined a function to insert a new node at the list

```
void addcar ( clist * h ){
    clist t ;
    t = (clist)malloc(sizeof(clinked)) ;
    (t->kar).readvalues();
    t->next = *h ;
    *h = t ;
    cout << "  Done \n\n" ;
}
```

The problem is when i call `addcar();` and i enter the `model` string value in the `readvalues();` function called to fill the new node's properties  , the program crashes . But it doesn't crash when i call `readvalues();`  on an object declared in `main();`

Is it an allocation problem ? A function call problem ? Thnx

Comment: You should find the person who told you to allocate C++ objects with malloc and tell them that you hate them.

Comment: And make sure you actually hate them with a vengeance. For about 5 minutes. Then, swap it for a feeling of smug superiority

Comment: Yes yes, let the malloc hate flow through you and your transformation to C++ will be complete.

Comment: use of malloc, -ve vote

Comment: @thecoshman Do you mean you're downvoting a question because it contains "the wrong problem to ask about?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `malloc()`, which allocates raw memory; it does not know anything about C++ classes and thus *does not call any constructors.*

You should steer clear of `malloc()` in C++ <sub>(except for very rare and usually extremely low-level tasks)</sub>.

Instead, use `new`, which will allocate the correct memory *and* call the constructors involved:

```
void addcar ( clist & h ){
    clist t = new clinked();
    t->kar.readvalues();
    t->next = h ;
    h = t ;
    cout << "  Done \n\n" ;
}
```

I've also changed the function to take its argument by reference instead of by pointer (as that's the C++ way of doing pass-by-reference).

---

Additional notes:

- If you want to implement your own linked list for learning purposes, you can of course, but I wouldn't recommend this to a C++ and/or OOP beginner. You're much better off using standard library's [`std::list<car>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).
- Don't use the C-ism of `typedef struct X { ... } X;`. C++ has the same space of names for struct tags and other names, so just do `struct X { ... };`. This still allows you to use `X` to refer to the type, no need to spell it out as `struct X`.
- It's generally a bad idea to hide pointers behind typedefs, as it makes code much harder to read. Simply use `clinked*` explicitly, the code's semantics will be much more obvious.
- In modern C++, you want to stay away from raw pointers owning memory - it's much better to use a smart pointer (like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) for that.

Comment: Thanx , problem solved , malloc was the sinner ! Thanks again

Comment: @reaffer: Hopefully you took on board all the rest of the advice in this answer. It's important stuff.

Comment: Also want to consider that allocating memory dynamically should be avoided. Favour using things 'automatically'. If you want an object of type `foo`, just make one `foo myFoo` rather than creating one dynamically. Tends to me for much easier code to work with. Of course, dynamically allocated memory is something you will need in places, but should be used because you need it, not because that's just what you know.

Comment: @thecoshman True in general, of course. However, note that that's what the OP is actually doing here - the `car kar` has automatic storage duration, and as `clinked` is an element of a linked list, it pretty much has to be dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `malloc`, this is wrong when you init a `string` member.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `malloc` to create instances of C++ classes, use `new`. This will ensure that all constructors are called, and that your member variables are correctly initialized.

Also, don't use `typedef struct` in C++. It's a C-ism and not required any more.